# Running heterogeneous jobs in multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, multithreading, pool

I have to load data from 15 different sources in a batch job nightly.  I'd like to process these in parallel but only 3 at a time because the database I'm querying disconnects me if resource load is too high.

```
import load_BW as BW
import load_CS as CS
import load_DM as DM
import load_ECG as ECG
import load_FA as FA
import load_FW as FW
import load_LB as LB
import load_MA as MA
import load_MI as MI
import load_OE as OE
import load_OM as OM
import load_PC as PC
import load_PP as PP
import load_TS as TS
import load_VS as VS
import multiprocessing
import RedShiftLoader as loader
import time

NUM_PROCESSES = 4

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loader.flush_tables()
    t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=BW.process).start()
    t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=CS.process).start()
    t3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=DM.process).start()
    t4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=ECG.process).start()
    t5 = multiprocessing.Process(target=FA.process).start()
    t6 = multiprocessing.Process(target=FW.process).start()
    t7 = multiprocessing.Process(target=LB.process).start()
    t8 = multiprocessing.Process(target=MA.process).start()
    t9 = multiprocessing.Process(target=MI.process).start()
    t10 = multiprocessing.Process(target=OE.process).start()
    t11 = multiprocessing.Process(target=OM.process).start()
    t12 = multiprocessing.Process(target=PC.process).start()
    t13 = multiprocessing.Process(target=PP.process).start()
    t14 = multiprocessing.Process(target=TS.process).start()
    t15 = multiprocessing.Process(target=VS.process).start()
```

How do I map heterogenous jobs to a Pool?  Al lof the examples I see online show the same job being run in parallel.

```
def doubler(number):
    return number * 2

pool = Pool(processes=3)
print(pool.map(doubler, numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap the task you want to do into a function that takes a consistent set of arguments, the arguments can vary widely to achieve a heterogeneous set of jobs.

For example, if you also use `subprocess`, you can run an arbitrary set of processes in parallel:

```py
import multiprocessing  
import subprocess  
  
  
def run(executable, arguments):  
    args = [executable] + arguments  
    return subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True, text=True)  
  
  
stuff_to_run = [  
    ("java", ["--version"]),  
    ("python", ["--version"]),  
    ("ls", ["-l", "/usr/bin"]),  
    ("pwd", []),  
]  
  
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:  
        results = pool.starmap(run, stuff_to_run)  
    
    # Now results should be a list of subprocess.CompletedProcess objects, one for each command we ran.  
    for result in results:  
        print(result.stdout)
```

As another example, if you have a collection of objects that each have a `run` method, you can write a simple function (or a lambda) that takes the object and calls its `run` method, and then get a heterogeneous workload by using different types of objects.

```py
import multiprocessing

stuff_to_run = [thing1, thing2, ...]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(lambda x: x.run(), stuff_to_run)

    # Now results will be a list of whatever gets returned by each object's `run` method
```